# How to create a grouped bar chart in Altair?

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

How does one create a grouped bar chart in Altair? I'm trying the following but it is just producing two graphs side by side.

```
Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
   column='Gender',
   x='Genre',
   y='Rating',
   color='Gender'
)
```

[image: This is the image produce]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Example of group bar chart**

I show a simplified example of [Grouped Bar Chart](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart.html) from Altair's documentation. You can  also see the full documentation [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/).

Basically, you have to specify x-axis `Gender` (F or M in each subplot), y-axis as `Rating` and `Genre` as `Column`.

```
from altair import *
import pandas as pd

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([['Action', 5, 'F'], 
                   ['Crime', 10, 'F'], 
                   ['Action', 3, 'M'], 
                   ['Crime', 9, 'M']], 
                  columns=['Genre', 'Rating', 'Gender'])

chart = Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
   column=Column('Genre'),
   x=X('Gender'),
   y=Y('Rating'),
   color=Color('Gender', scale=Scale(range=['#EA98D2', '#659CCA']))
).configure_facet_cell(
    strokeWidth=0.0,
)

chart.display() # will show the plot
```

The bar chart will look like following

[image]

**Adding Axis parameters**

You only have to follow `Axis` parameters in documentation to make the plot looks prettier:

```
chart = Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
   column=Column('Genre', 
                 axis=Axis(axisWidth=1.0, offset=-8.0, orient='bottom'),
                 scale=Scale(padding=4.0)),
   x=X('Gender', axis=False),
   y=Y('Rating', axis=Axis(grid=False)),
   color=Color('Gender', scale=Scale(range=['#EA98D2', '#659CCA']))
).configure_facet_cell(
    strokeWidth=0.0,
)

chart.display()
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Could you explain the '.transform_data' section?

It seems really involved just to get a grouped bar chart. I'm just starting out with data visualization so I don't know how this compares to other libraries.

Comment: @KrisCampos, so Altair use grammar for plotting from `vega` and `vega-lite`. The syxtax will be heavily rely on these two. Transform basically specified fields that you can put to filter out or mapping data. See more on https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/transform.html. For me, I feel like we don't mandatory need it since we can do filtering and cleaning up part using pandas directly.

Comment: Note that I just remove transformation part cause it doesn't affect the plot actually, haha.

Comment: The Altair documentation link for grouped bar charts is now updated to [this page](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart.html).

Comment: Thanks @WR! I can update my solution and link it to the documentation page.

Comment: `configure_facet_cell` has been removed. To remove the facet outlines now just replace it with `configure_view`.

Comment: I think these configuration are outdated because I get an error alt.Axis inside the column specification, do we have an updated version of the parameters to change to make the plot look like the second plot? (instead of the library example that looks like the first one)

Comment: Yes please, can you make a suggestion to this answer? @Carolina

Comment: great answer! the colors are a bit stereotype though ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you try the accepted answers on newer version of Altair (since 4.2.0). You will notice that it doesn't work. Some of the API has changed, so to get the same results in Altair 4.2.0 you can use the approach posted in my answer to [Grouped bar chart in newer versions of altair (>= 4.2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72084295/grouped-bar-chart-in-newer-versions-of-altair-4-2-0/72088754#72088754). For the development version of Altair (which will probably be released as 5.0), this has become easier to achieve since you can use the `xOffset` encoding like this without the need to facet your charts:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Action', 5, 'F'], 
                   ['Crime', 10, 'F'], 
                   ['Action', 3, 'M'], 
                   ['Crime', 9, 'M']], 
                  columns=['Genre', 'Rating', 'Gender'])

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
   x=alt.X('Genre', axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=0)),
   xOffset='Gender',
   y=alt.Y('Rating', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)),
   color='Gender'
).configure_view(
    stroke=None,
)

chart
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work in 5.0.1 despite having xOffset support.  It just shows 2 stacked bars.

Comment: @Cassova It works for me, if you recently upgraded to altair 5, make sure you have closed any notebook using altair 4, and then restart your IDE. Having figures with altair 4 plots showing can prevent the upgrade. If that doesn't work, please submit a bug report on github with more details