# Sorting Altair column order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, altair

I am new to using Altair and have crudely combined some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787209/how-to-have-clusters-of-stacked-bars-with-python-pandas) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797379/how-to-create-a-grouped-bar-chart-in-altair) which gives me the plot below but I cannot work out why my columns are shown in a non-sequential order.  My dataframe is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

TimeMth = pd.DataFrame([['Jul-2011', '> 1.1 pu',  86],
                       ['Jul-2011', '< 0.94 pu',  18],
                       ['Aug-2011', '> 1.1 pu',  205],
                       ['Aug-2011', '< 0.94 pu', 510],
                       ['Sep-2011', '> 1.1 pu',   53],
                       ['Sep-2011', '< 0.94 pu', 140],
                       ['Oct-2011', '> 1.1 pu',   10],
                       ['Oct-2011', '< 0.94 pu',   0],
                       ['Nov-2011', '> 1.1 pu',   36],
                       ['Nov-2011', '< 0.94 pu',  13],
                       ['Dec-2011', '> 1.1 pu',    7],
                       ['Dec-2011', '< 0.94 pu',   0],
                       ['Jan-2012', '> 1.1 pu',   17],
                       ['Jan-2012', '< 0.94 pu',   0],
                       ['Feb-2012', '> 1.1 pu',    0],
                       ['Feb-2012', '< 0.94 pu',   0],
                       ['Mar-2012', '> 1.1 pu',   17],
                       ['Mar-2012', '< 0.94 pu',   1],
                       ['Apr-2012', '> 1.1 pu',   49],
                       ['Apr-2012', '< 0.94 pu',  79],
                       ['May-2012', '> 1.1 pu',    8],
                       ['May-2012', '< 0.94 pu',   0],
                       ['Jun-2012', '> 1.1 pu',   40],
                       ['Jun-2012', '< 0.94 pu',  12]],
                    columns=['Month','Voltage','No of Violations'])
```

which I then attempt to plot with:

```
import altair as alt

chartTimeMth = alt.Chart(TimeMth).mark_bar().encode(
column=alt.Column('Month',
            axis=alt.Axis(axisWidth=1.0, 
               offset=-8.0, orient='bottom', labelAngle=-45, 
labelAlign='right'),
            scale=alt.Scale(padding=4.0)),
x=alt.X('Voltage',
       axis=False),
y=alt.Y('No of Violations', title='No. of voltage violations', 
axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)),
color=alt.Color('Voltage', scale=alt.Scale(range=['#96ceb4', '#ffcc5c']))
).configure_facet_cell(
strokeWidth=0.0,)\
.configure_scale(bandSize=12)\
.configure_legend(titleFontSize=12, offset=-60, orient='right')

chartTimeMth.display()
```

When I use [sortField](https://altair-viz.github.io/API.html?highlight=sort#altair.SortField) on the columns it gets close to what I need but still not right.  I guess this is something to do with the fact that my column (Month) data is text?  Any ideas on why the above code (with the *sortField* class omitted) does not plot the columns in index order?
If my *Month* data was *datetimeindex*, is there a way to tell Altair to label the x-axis as I have below (ie mmm-yyyy)?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can specify the [data type](https://altair-viz.github.io/documentation/encoding.html#data-types) using the `type` keyword.

```
column=alt.Column('Month',type='temporal', ....
```

You can also use [Encoding Shorthands](https://altair-viz.github.io/documentation/encoding.html#shorthand-description) to define the data type

```
column=alt.Column('Month:T', ...
```

As for the formatting of the axis you can pass the `format` keyword a [date directive string](http://strftime.org/) when you make your axis

```
axis = alt.Axis(..., format='%b-%Y')
```

Here is the your previous code with the above changes made.

```
chartTimeMth = alt.Chart(TimeMth).mark_bar().encode(
    column=alt.Column(
        'Month:T',
        axis=alt.Axis(
            axisWidth=1.0, 
            offset=-8.0, 
            orient='bottom', 
            labelAngle=-45, 
            labelAlign='right', 
            format='%b-%Y'
        ),
        scale=alt.Scale(padding=4.0)
    ),
    x=alt.X('Voltage', axis=False),
    y=alt.Y(
        'No of Violations', 
        title='No. of voltage violations', 
        axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)),
        color=alt.Color(
            'Voltage', 
            scale=alt.Scale(range=['#96ceb4', '#ffcc5c'])
    )
).configure_facet_cell(strokeWidth=0.0,)\
 .configure_scale(bandSize=12)\
 .configure_legend(titleFontSize=12, offset=-60, orient='right')
```

[image]