# altair grouped bar chart side-by-side instead of single chart

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

I tried creating the chart however it ends up showing two charts side-by-side.
How do I get a single chart instead like the one shown in altair grouped bar chart [example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart.html).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'strike': [200,225,250,275,300,325,350,200,225,250,275,300,325,350],
    'opttype': ['ce','ce','ce','ce','ce','ce','ce','pe','pe','pe','pe','pe','pe','pe' ],
    'oi': [100,150,500,800,450,200,77,50,500,210,300,150,60,17]
    
})
c = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='strike:N',
    y='oi:Q',
    color='opttype:N',
    column='opttype:N'
)
```

Output
[image: output]

I tried adding axis as specified in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797379/how-to-create-a-grouped-bar-chart-in-altair), however I could not get the combined graph. May be I am missing something here.

Also I wonder how the official documentation example works correcly without the "axis" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current best way to do this is to switch your `x` and `column` encodings, then make the width of each panel narrower:

```python
c = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='opttype:N',
    y='oi:Q',
    color='opttype:N',
    column='strike:N'
).properties(width=50)
```

[image]

Then, if you wish, you can adjust axis & heading labels as in the linked examples. For example, you can move the header labels to the bottom like this:

```python
c = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('opttype:N', axis=None),
    y='oi:Q',
    color='opttype:N',
    column=alt.Column('strike:N', header=alt.Header(orient='bottom'))
).properties(width=50)
```

[image]

This is admittedly an imperfect solution. Vega-Lite is in the process of adding an `offset` encoding that will make this possible without having to use multiple column facets, but that is not available yet.

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp, this works. The offset would make this nicer. I'll play around to remove the labels (ce/pe) at the bottom. Also wondering if there is a way to get the Strike values at the bottom instead of the current position (at the top). My mind is trained to view the values at the bottom for X-axis.

Comment: Yes, the answer you linked to in your question shows how to move the heading labels to the bottom.

Comment: The example linked uses **"axis="** on the Column type which I do not see supported in the [latest docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/channels/altair.Column.html). The "spacing" option helped reduce the gap between the bars.

Comment: OK, see my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

The x-axis and color variable should be the same:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'strike': [200,225,250,275,300,325,350,200,225,250,275,300,325,350],
    'opttype': ['ce','ce','ce','ce','ce','ce','ce','pe','pe','pe','pe','pe','pe','pe' ],
    'oi': [100,150,500,800,450,200,77,50,500,210,300,150,60,17]
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='opttype:N',
    y='oi:Q',
    color='opttype:N',
    column='strike:N'
)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @joelosblom for your answer. I just chose the previous as the accepted answer as that came in a few seconds earlier.