# Grouped bar charts in Altair using two different columns

Tags: python, plot, bar-chart, altair

**TLDR; How do I make a grouped bar chart in the most recent version of Altair where the grouped bars come from different columns of quantitative data, as opposed to one column of categorical data?**

While I've found some great answers on here about creating grouped bar charts in Altair (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72084295/grouped-bar-chart-in-newer-versions-of-altair-4-2-0/72088754#72088754)), none answer my specific question.

I have a table with multiple columns, two of which are quantitative and represent two different values that could be grouped into one category (e.g. 'cm_of_rain' and 'cm_of_snow' can be summed and called something like 'cm_of_precipitation'), one is the months as ordinal strings, and another is the day as a number. So a dataframe of the data would look something like this:

```
data = {'Month':['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Apr'], 
        'Day': [1, 15, 1, 15, 1, 15, 1, 15],
        'cm_of_rain':[20, 21, 19, 18, 1, 12, 33, 12], 
        'cm_of_snow':[0, 2, 6, 3, 4, 2, 5 ,11]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

 Month  Day  cm_of_rain  cm_of_snow
   Jan    1          20           0
   Jan   15          21           2
   Feb    1          19           6
   Feb   15          18           3
   Mar    1           1           4
   Mar   15          12           2
   Apr    1          33           5
   Apr   15          12          11
```

I want to make a bar plot where the data is grouped by month on the X axis and cm of precipitation is shown on the Y-axis, but rather than having a stacked bar plot where rain and snow are additive, I want to plot the two values as side-by-side bars for each month. So the result should look something like the grouped bar plot from the post linked above

[image: Example of a grouped bar chart, taken from this linked StackOverflow post.]

except Genre ("Action", "Crime") would be replaced by Month ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"), Gender (F, M) would be replaced by Precipitation_Type (rain, snow), and Rating would be replaced by Precipitation_(cm).

For context, the main difference between my question and the ones asked by others before, is that the data I want to group together is from two different columns of quantitative data in my dataframe, whereas every other post I've seen uses some sort of categorical data from a single column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is usually referred to as "wide form" or "untidy" data. Altair generally works better with "long form" or "tidy data". You can [read more about how to convert between the two in the documentation,](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) but one way would be to use `transform_fold`.

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd


data = {'Month':['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Apr'], 
        'Day': [1, 15, 1, 15, 1, 15, 1, 15],
        'rain':[20, 21, 19, 18, 1, 12, 33, 12], 
        'snow':[0, 2, 6, 3, 4, 2, 5 ,11]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='amount (cm):Q',
    y='type:N',
    color='type:N',
    row=alt.Row('Month', sort=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'])
).transform_fold(
    as_=['type', 'amount (cm)'],
    fold=['rain', 'snow']
)
```

[image]

Comment: I followed this code, but my graph doesn't showed the Month part with all the month name. (I used this on streamlit btw)