# How to add error bars in Altair based on different columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python, plot, bar-chart, altair, grouped-bar-chart

So I have columns of data, one of which is the average - which I want to show, and one of which is the std deviation - which I want the error bars of

I'm starting using altair, but I have quite a bit of data like this and would like to initially use it for altair.

setting up the dataframe:

```
nums = 6
testmean = [np.random.rand()*25+75 for _ in range(nums)]
teststdev = [np.random.rand()*5 for _ in range(nums)]
testspecies = ['oak', 'elm', 'willow']
testspecies = 2*(nums//len(testspecies))*testspecies
testfert = [True for _ in range(nums//2)] + [False for _ in range(nums//2)]
testfert = 2*testfert
testmetric = ['average' for _ in range(nums)] + ['stdev' for _ in range(nums)]

testnums = testmean + teststdev
testset = zip(testnums, testspecies, testfert, testmetric, strict=True)
testdf = pd.DataFrame(testset, columns = ['number', 'species', 'fertilizer', 'type'])
```

I created the bars like I wanted:

```
bars = alt.Chart(testdf.loc[testdf['type'] == 'average']).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('fertilizer', title = None),
    alt.Y('number', title = 'mean'),
    color='fertilizer',
    column='species',
    tooltip=['species']
)
```

and this should work for the error bars:

```
error_bars = alt.Chart(testdf.loc[testdf['type'] == 'stdev').mark_errorbar(extent='ci').encode(
    alt.X('fertilizer', title = None),
    alt.Y('number'),
    column='species',
    tooltip=['species']
)
```

but I have no idea how to combine the two, and it looks like facet won't work as the data isn't in 'long form' and produces the error `Faceted charts cannot be layered` when trying to layer it with `bars+error_bars`:

```
alt.layer(bars, error_bars, data=testdf).facet(
    column='species'
)
```

[Grouped bar charts in Altair using two different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72181211/grouped-bar-charts-in-altair-using-two-different-columns) introduced the concept of long form but doesn't really help answer the question in a way I could see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, you can't layer faceted chart, but you can facet layered charts. So removing the `column=` from the individual charts and only using it in the facet will work:

```py
wide_df = testdf.pivot(index=['species', 'fertilizer'], columns='type', values='number').reset_index()

bars = alt.Chart().mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('fertilizer', title = None),
    alt.Y('average', title='mean'),
    color='fertilizer',
    # column='species',
    tooltip=['species']
)

error_bars = alt.Chart().mark_rule().encode(
    alt.X('fertilizer', title=None),
    alt.Y('errbar_min:Q'),
    alt.Y2('errbar_max:Q'),
    # column='species',
    tooltip=['species']
).transform_calculate(
    errbar_min = alt.datum.average - alt.datum.stdev / 2,
    errbar_max = alt.datum.average + alt.datum.stdev / 2
)

alt.layer(bars, error_bars, data=wide_df).facet(
    column='species'
)
```

[image]

Comment: It seems the species are the same and the sort is based on max number and not on species. It is much better than I started with though

Comment: @user3452643 That is because of how your individual charts were set up, I added an example with the correct setup