# Altair Python horizontal bar graph with two variables in the same frame

Tags: python, bar-chart, altair

Using Altair, how can I plot in the same horizontal bar plot two variables that are in the same data frame?

I have a panda data frame that looks like this:

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [['AAA','71.15','FOUSA06C1Y'],
['AA','2.93','FOUSA06C1Y'],
['A','11.9','FOUSA06C1Y'],
['BBB','14.04','FOUSA06C1Y'],
['BB','0.0','FOUSA06C1Y'],
['B','0.0','FOUSA06C1Y'],
['Below B','0.0','FOUSA06C1Y'],
['Not Rated','-0.02','FOUSA06C1Y'],
['AAA','34.81744518','1404'],
['AA','47.24845367','1404'],
['A','16.66257244','1404'],
['BBB','1.271528716','1404'],
['BB / B','0.0','1404'],
['Below B','0.0','1404'],
['Short Term Rated','0.0','1404'],
['Not Rated','0.0','1404'],
['Nan','0.0','1404']]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['index', 'value','fund'])

df['value'] = df['value'].astype(float)
```

I am able to *separately* horizontal bar plot these with below code:

```
gp_chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('value'),
    alt.Y('index', axis=alt.Axis(grid=True)), 
    alt.Color('fund'),
    alt.Row('fund')
    )

gp_chart
```

Which will produce this separated graphs:

[image]

Picking part of this graph as an example (just picking A and AAA), I want to see these bars together like this:
[image]

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72181211/grouped-bar-charts-in-altair-using-two-different-columns).

Answer (score 1):

I lack experience with altair, but I can use the filter function to create a graph with only positive values by setting the values above and below 0 and non-zero.

```
import altair as alt
from altair import datum

gp_chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('value'),
    alt.Y('index', axis=alt.Axis(grid=True)), 
    alt.Color('fund'),
    alt.Row('fund')
    ).transform_filter(
    (datum.value != 0) & (datum.value >= 0)
)

gp_chart
```

[image]

***New Version 5.0.0rc1***
Although not officially released yet, it appears that grouping is possible with the latest version of the functionality. See this [page](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart2.html)

```
pip install altair==5.0.0rc1
import altair as alt
from altair import datum

gp_chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('value'),
    alt.Y('index', axis=alt.Axis(grid=True)), 
    alt.Color('fund'),
    yOffset='fund'
    ).transform_filter(
    (datum.value != 0) & (datum.value >= 0)
)

gp_chart
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, however, I need to have the orange and blue graph in the same frame/graph. For example, in order, I need to have A for the "1404" and then the A for the "FOUSA06C1Y", then AA for the "1404" and then the AA for the "FOUSA06C1Y" if that makes sense.